# JavaFX restarting with Spring Dev Tools

Tags: spring, javafx, spring-boot

So, in most of my projects I use [Spring Dev Tools](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) because it allows me to make source code changes and automatically reload the app. I'm now developing a spring app and using JavaFX for some things. However, the launch(String...args) method of the JavaFX Application class does not allow launch to be called more than once. It throws the following error when Spring Dev Tools tries to re-run the main method. Any workaround for this? The spring application context successfully reloads, but the JavaFX stuff does not.

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called more than once
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:162)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:143)
at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:252)
```

Comment: If you are using eclipse or some other IDE, you can get the same result by launching your app in debug mode and using code hotswap

Comment: @yamenK does that mean there is no way to do this with spring dev tools and alternative is to use code swap? If I use code swap with it still try to restart the main method and get the same error?